# How to generate a series of (x,y) coordinates from a series of images in Python?

Tags: python, pixel

If I have a series of shapes in .jpg, .png etc. that are all [stroked](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/painting.html#Definitions) is there a way to parse those images and output a set of x,y coordinates to re-draw the shape in whatever application e.g. iOS, Android etc. Ideally I'd love if I can mirror the coordinate system with the origin point 0,0 starting from the top left but not sure if that's possible to do.

These stroked shapes will most likely be black/white images.

Example of a possible image:

[image]

I feel like it's possible as an image is just a series of pixels but I'm not sure how to go about it. Python preferred but any other language is also OK.

Answer (score 2):

you can use module `PIL` and `numpy` to do it.

code:

```
from PIL import Image
from numpy import asarray

#convert your png file to data
img = Image.open('Sample.png')
print(list(img.getdata()))
numpydata = asarray(img)

#re-draw the picture from data
redraw_img = Image.fromarray(numpydata)
redraw_img.show()#show a picture exactly the same as the OP's picture
```

result:

```
[(1, 1, 1), (0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2), (6, 6, 6), (12, 12, 12), (17, 17, 17), (33, 33, 33), (51, 51, 51), (75, 75, 75), (105, 105, 105), (134, 134, 134), (164, 164, 164), (192, 192, 192), (211, 211, 211), (228, 228, 228), (239, 239, 239), (246, 246, 246), (254, 254, 254), (255, 255, 255), (254, 254, 254), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (254, 254, 254), (254, 254, 254), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (254, 254, 254), (254, 254, 254), (253, 253, 253), (253, 253, 253), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (254, 254, 254), (254, 254, 254), (253, 253, 253), (253, 253, 253), (252, 252, 252), (249, 249, 249), (248, 248, 248), (247, 247, 247), (245, 245, 245), (243, 243, 243), (241, 241, 241), (239, 239, 239), (237, 237, 237), (239, 239, 239), (237, 237, 237), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (236, 236, 236), (236, 236, 236), (236, 236, 236), (236, 236, 236), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (235, 235, 235), (234, 234, 234), (234, 234, 234), (234, 234, 234), (234, 234, 234), (233, 233, 233), (232, 232, 232), (231, 231, 231), (231, 231, 231), (231, 231, 231), (228, 228, 228), (223, 223, 223), (219, 219, 219), (214, 214, 214), (207, 207, 207), (197, 197, 197), (187, 187, 187), (177, 177, 177), (166, 166, 166), (154, 154, 154), (146, 146, 146), (134, 
134, 134), (127, 127, 127), (118, 118, 118), (111, 111, 111), (108, 108, 108), (105, 105, 105), (102, 102, 102), (99, 99, 99), (97, 97, 97), (97, 97, 97), (96, 96, 96), (96, 96, 96), (96, 96, 96), (96, 96, 96), (97, 97, 97), (97, 97, 97), (96, 96, 96), (98, 98, 98), (100, 100, 100), (103, 103, 103), (106, 106, 106), (110, 110, 110), (114, 114, 114), (117, 117, 117), (123, 123, 123), (128, 128, 128), (135, 135, 135), (140, 140, 140), (145, 145, 145), (151, 151, 151), (161, 161, 161), (168, 168, 168), (173, 173, 173), (179, 179, 179), (188, 188, 188), (194, 194, 194), (200, 200, 200), (206, 206, 206), (214, 214, 214), (220, 220, 220), (224, 224, 224), (228, 228, 228), (233, 233, 233), (238, 238, 238), (241, 241, 241), (243, 243, 243), (246, 246, 246), (248, 248, 248), (249, 249, 249), (250, 250, 250), (251, 251, 251), (252, 252, 252), (253, 253, 253), (253, 253, 253), (254, 254, 254), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (254, 254, 254), (253, 253, 253), (252, 252, 252), (253, 253, 253), (253, 253, 253), (250, 250, 250), (247, 247, 247), (245, 245, 245), (243, 243, 243), (238, 238, 238), (232, 232, 232), (226, 226, 226), (218, 218, 218), (211, 211, 211), (202, 202, 202), (193, 193, 193), (187, 187, 187), (180, 180, 180), (172, 172, 172), (166, 166, 166), (163, 163, 163), (160, 160, 160), (159, 159, 159), (160, 160, 160), (164, 164, 164), (168, 168, 168), (177, 177, 177), (185, 185, 185), (196, 196, 196), (203, 203, 203), (214, 214, 214), (224, 224, 224), (231, 231, 231), (238, 238, 238), (244, 244, 244), (248, 248, 248), (251, 251, 251), (254, 254, 254), (254, 254, 254), (253, 253, 253), (253, 253, 253), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 
255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), 
(255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (1, 1, 1), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (5, 5, 5), (11, 11, 11), (18, 18, 18), (34, 34, 34), (51, 51, 51), (75, 75, 75), (105, 105, 105), (133, 133, 133), (162, 162, 162), (190, 190, 190), (212, 212, 212), (228, 228, 228), (239, 239, 
239), (245, 245, 245), (254, 254, 254), (255, 255, 255), (254, 254, 254), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (254, 254, 254), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (254, 254, 254), (254, 254, 254), (254, 254, 254), (253, 253, 253), (253, 253, 253), (252, 252, 252), (251, 251, 251), (250, 250, 250), (248, 248, 248), (247, 247, 247), (244, 244, 244), (242, 242, 242), (240, 240, 240), (237, 237, 237), (235, 235, 235), (232, 232, 232), (228, 228, 228), (226, 226, 226), (225, 225, 225), (224, 224, 224), (222, 222, 222), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (222, 222, 222), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (221, 221, 221), (220, 220, 220), (220, 220, 220), (220, 220, 220), (220, 220, 220), (219, 219, 219), (220, 220, 220), (219, 219, 219), (217, 217, 217), (217, 217, 217), (216, 216, 216), (213, 213, 213), (208, 208, 208), (203, 203, 203), (196, 196, 196), (188, 188, 188), (177, 177, 177), (165, 165, 165), (154, 154, 154), (141, 141, 141), (128, 128, 128), (119, 119, 119), (108, 108, 108), (102, 102, 102), (93, 93, 93), (86, 86, 86), (83, 83, 83), (80, 80, 80), (77, 77, 77), (74, 74, 74), (72, 72, 72), (72, 72, 72), (71, 71, 71), (71, 71, 71), (71, 71, 71), (71, 71, 71), (72, 72, 72), (72, 72, 72), (71, 71, 71), (73, 73, 73), (76, 76, 
76), (78, 78, 78), (80, 80, 80), (84, 84, 84), (88, 88, 88), (91, 91, 91), (96, 96, 96), (101, 101, 101), (108, 108, 108), (113, 113, 113), (117, 117, 117), (124, 124, 124), (133, 133, 133), (140, 140, 140), (150, 150, 150), (156, 156, 156), (165, 165, 165), (172, 172, 172), (179, 179, 179), (187, 187, 187), (195, 195, 195), (202, 202, 202), (210, 210, 210), (215, 215, 215), (222, 222, 222), (228, 228, 228), (232, 232, 232), (236, 236, 236), (239, 239, 239), (242, 242, 242), (245, 245, 245), (247, 247, 247), (249, 249, 249), (250, 250, 250), (251, 251, 251), (251, 251, 251), (252, 252, 252), (253, 253, 253), (253, 253, 253), (254, 254, 254), (254, 254, 254), (253, 253, 253), (252, 252, 252), (251, 251, 251), (250, 
250, 250), (250, 250, 250), (248, 248, 248), (245, 245, 245), (241, 241, 241), (238, 238, 238), (234, 234, 234), (228, 228, 228), (220, 220, 220), (213, 213, 213), (203, 203, 203), 
(195, 195, 195), (184, 184, 184), (173, 173, 173), (164, 164, 164), (156, 156, 156), (146, 146, 146), (140, 140, 140), (137, 137, 137), (134, 134, 134), (132, 132, 132), (134, 134, 
134), (138, 138, 138), (143, 143, 143), (152, 152, 152), (161, 161, 161), (175, 175, 175), (184, 184, 184), (197, 197, 197), (210, 210, 210), (220, 220, 220), (229, 229, 229), (237, 237, 237), (242, 242, 242), (247, 247, 247), (251, 251, 251), (253, 253, 253), (252, 252, 252), (253, 253, 253), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), ...
```

reference:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-images-to-numpy-array/

Comment: I will try this and loop back! Thank you for the suggestion. :] The output I'm not sure of but I'm sure it'll be clear once I try it