# How to render a 'Glass Jar' image in IOS app using SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, core-graphics

Newbie question. Please delete if this is not right forum. I am helping my 11 years old son enhance his simple text based IOS App. He wants to add a Glass Jar to his App. The goal is to use it to add ideas written on virtual post-it, into the Glass Jar. He wants to do the visual implementation. I have listed the steps we are looking for guidance.

Requesting help with the following questions.

1. Is it better to use an image of a glass jar or create it as custom graphics? An example image is attached.
2. If custom graphics, any pointers?
3. If an image, how to add the effect that ideas are accumulating in the jar.

[image]

Comment: "Is it better to use an image of a glass jar or create it as custom graphics?" That is pretty challenging to evaluate... What makes it "better" or "worse"? "If an image, how to add the effect that ideas are accumulating in the jar." This probably depends how you want them to look. Do they just need to be "inside" the jar? If so, pick a coordinate and draw them there.

Comment: @jnpdx Good point. Easy to drop virtual post-it notes in the 'Glass Jar'. My son wants notes to be visible. Not what is written but more from a count perspective. Any pointers on how to generate coordinates for such a shape? I tried irregular shapes and was not able to get a symmetrical shape.

Comment: Unfortunately, that question is far too vague for me to provide any sort of answer.

Comment: @jnpdx is there a tool where I can copy the above image and it can generate (x,y) coordinates at fine granularity? I used graph paper manually to generate (x,y) coordinates. Output is not symmetrical and edges are zagged as well.

Comment: I don't know of a tool to generate it. But opening it in an image editor and taking note of some of the coordinates would be certainly more precise than using graph paper.

Comment: @jnpdx I used python code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67931444/how-to-generate-a-series-of-x-y-coordinates-from-a-series-of-images-in-python. My son is ungated now. Thanks for your guidance.